# Can You Define Colors From java.awt In A Yaml File

Tags: java, yaml, awt

I was wondering if it was possible to define colors from the java.awt inside a yaml file as such?

```
# Button Colors
ButtonOneColor: Color.BLUE
ButtonTwoColor: Color.BLUE
ButtonThreeColor: Color.BLUE
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can define colors into yaml like in the question. You need to use [yaml readers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989576/how-to-read-from-yaml-file-in-java) to read that and assign accordingly in your program after.